# Converting a List of Variables into a data.table object

Tags: r, data.table

Is there a more elegant way of converting a list of variables into a data.table object?

This does not give the desired result.

```
require(data.table)
set.seed(1)
Var.List <- list(a=sample(letters, 10, rep=T),b=rnorm(10), c=rnorm(10))
data.table(Var.List)
```

The following does give the desired result, but is slow with big lists/tables.  Is there a better way?  I run into this problem quite often when aggregating results from the foreach package.

```
data.table(as.data.frame(Var.List))

    a          b           c
 1: g -0.8204684 -0.04493361
 2: j  0.4874291 -0.01619026
 3: o  0.7383247  0.94383621
 4: x  0.5757814  0.82122120
 5: f -0.3053884  0.59390132
 6: x  1.5117812  0.91897737
 7: y  0.3898432  0.78213630
 8: r -0.6212406  0.07456498
 9: q -2.2146999 -1.98935170
10: b  1.1249309  0.61982575
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit:** The best solution (h.t. Arun) is to just do `as.data.table(Var.List)`, invoking `as.data.table()`'s ready-made `"list"` method.

---

Just like `data.frame()`, `data.table()` will accept a data.frame, a matrix, **or** an arbitrary number of vectors as inputs, processing them via its `...` argument.

Taking advantage of the latter option, you can use `do.call()` to construct a `data.table` from a **list** of such vectors:

```
do.call(data.table, Var.List)
    a          b           c
 1: g -0.8204684 -0.04493361
 2: j  0.4874291 -0.01619026
 3: o  0.7383247  0.94383621
 4: x  0.5757814  0.82122120
 5: f -0.3053884  0.59390132
 6: x  1.5117812  0.91897737
 7: y  0.3898432  0.78213630
 8: r -0.6212406  0.07456498
 9: q -2.2146999 -1.98935170
10: b  1.1249309  0.61982575
```

Comment: That was easy! Thanks so much!

Comment: In this case, also, you can modify in-place with `setDT(Var.List)`. Or using `as.data.table(.)` which has a `list` method.

Comment: @Arun -- Thanks. Those are much nicer.